# Form input values using jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following is a snippet of my form

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;" id="program_name_1">Basics</span>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/programs/1" class="edit_program" data-remote="true" id="edit_program_1" method="post">
    <input id="program_name" name="program[name]" size="30" type="text" value="Basics" />
</form>
```

Here is the jquery I'm trying to use

```
function set_updated_program_values(id)
{
  $('#program_name_' + id).html($('#edit_program_' + id + ' input:#program_name').val());
  alert('new name is ' + $('#edit_program_' + id + ' input:#program_name').val());
}
```

The span tag isn't being updated, and the alert says it is undefined.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're referring to your `input`. You can use `input:#program_name`. You should just use `#program_name`.

**Example:**

```
$('#edit_program_' + id + ' #program_name').val()
```

Comment: You're right, I could have sworn I was doing it like that on another application.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have the same `IDs` for different elements of your HTML code.
2. Have you linked the `set_updated_program_values` function to an event? If not, it can't be triggered by itself...

Try this HTML code...

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;" id="program_name_1">Basics</span>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/programs/1" class="edit_program" data-remote="true" id="edit_program_1" method="post">
    <input name="program[name]" size="30" type="text" value="Basics" />
</form>
```

...with this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var changeText = function(){
        var id = this.parentNode.id.split('_')[2];
        var value = this.value.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        $('#program_name_' + id).html(value);
    };

    $('form.edit_program input:text').change(changeText).keyup(changeText);

});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/creaweb/BgtBv/ (working example online)